# How to use FastButtons for them to work on mobile devices?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have read this (and other relating things also):

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?hl=fi#conclusion

but I don't understand how to use this in Google Apps Script. I made the UI with GUI Builder and now I want the buttons to work also on mobile devices.

Could someone please explain to me with a code example of how to change my buttons to work also on mobile devices?

---

Code that works Ok on PC but not on mobile device:

```
var handler109 = app.createServerClickHandler('func109');
var but109 = app.getElementById('Button109');
but109.addClickHandler(handler109);
```

How to use Client Handler? app.createClientHandler('func109') generates an error, app.createClientClickHandler('func109') generates an error...  How do I define that function func109 should be called?

```
var handler109 = app.createClientHandler();
var but109 = app.getElementById('Button109');
but109.addClickHandler(handler109);
```

Comment: A clientHandler cannot call a function.... only serverHandler can do it since the script is executed **on the server** , see [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clienthandler?hl=fr-FR) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the article you've shared is applicable for mobile and not so much for Google Apps Scripts.

However, the buttons you make in Google Apps Script WILL work on mobile devices too. However, if you only have a server handler set up on the button, it will take a noticeable period of time before the action of the button is seen by the user.

Google Apps Script also has [client handlers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_clienthandler?hl=en) which you can use which show up a much faster response than server handlers.

[Issue 1086](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1086) might be relevant in your case

Comment: You're right, this is what I need! :-) But... I have problems using this. How do I tell the client handler which function to call when the button is presed? See code above.

Comment: As Serge pointed out, you cannot call functions within client handlers. Client handlers are not for elaborate processing but only for indicating progress to the user or such simple tasks. All the heavy lifting must be done in a server handler.

Comment: The send-button in the built in contact form works also on my mobile device and Srik wrote "However, the buttons you make in Google Apps Script WILL work on mobile devices too." So is there a work around possibility to get my button work on mobile devices?

Comment: Srik: Issue 1086 might be relevant in your case: "Buttons generated from code DOES NOT require he above process to work. As soon as I touch the button, the event will fire." I tried to create the button from CODE but the behaviour was the same: Pushing the button from PC fires the event but from mobile device not... Is there some way to get a button work in mobile devices too?

Comment: Yes, I use Samsung GIO. "Fast" double click zooms the screen out. A little bit slower double click does nothing.